# Laravel accessing session array values in different fields

Tags: json, laravel-5.3

> I have an array in json format and i want to access its value in my different form fields

```
{"title":"title2","assessment_type":"type2","no_of_words":"250","deadline":"2017-01-04"}
```

> how can i get the values i have wasted a whole day for this please help
>   i am saving session like this

```
 $order = new Order();
        $order->title = $request->get('subject');
        $order->assessment_type = $request->get('assessment_type');
        $order->no_of_words = $request->get('no_of_words');
        $order->deadline = $request->get('date');
        Session::put('order_info', $order);
        return redirect()->route('update-order');
```

> for getting i have tried

```
{{Session::get("order_info")[$title]}},
 {{ json_decode(Session::get('order_info')->title) }},
{{ in_array('order_info', $title)}}
```

> all in vain please help